# Can numpy.genfromtxt() returns list of column data, not row data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file which looks something like

```
col1 col2 col3
1    4    7
2    5    8
3    6    9
```

and I am trying to produce a list of lists containing the *column* data:

```
[ [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9] ]
```

but the following code produces a list of row data, i.e. `[ [1,4,7], ... ]`.

```
blah = np.genfromtxt(scrubbed_file, skip_header=1)
for bluh in blah:
    print(bluh)
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Ok I got it. Will post answer in a sec

Answer (score 2):

you can just transpose the resulting array like so: 
`blah = np.genfromtxt(scrubbed_file, skip_header=1).T`
This will effectively put the array on it's side, resulting in the data format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the unpack variable from `genfromtext`:

```
np.genfromtxt('text.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True, skip_header=1)
```

It gives the following:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very convenient python feature that does exactly this, namely `zip(*list)`:

```
blah = np.genfromtxt(scrubbed_file, skip_header=1)
for bluh in zip(*blah):
    print(bluh)
```